# Running shell script in WxWidgets

Tags: shell, wxwidgets

I need to run shell script from `WxWidgets` application.
Is there a possibility to execute `shell script` from `WxWidgets` application?

If so, I want to learn how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `wxExecute()`

```
wxExecute("/path/to/your/script");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute an external application (be it a shell script or not), you should indeed use [wxExecute()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0.2/group__group__funcmacro__procctrl.html#gaa276e9e676e26bafeec3141b73399b33) as already mentioned in the other answer.

If you want to run a shell built-in command, or use other shell-specific features such as IO redirection, you need to use [wxShell()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0.2/group__group__funcmacro__procctrl.html#gad7f2f357f592f8c786ab05f516578023).